# Create factory pattern

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to use the factory pattern and have created three interfaces.

**ITest1**

```
public interface ITest1: ITestX
{
    void Write(string name);
}
```

**ITest2**

```
public interface ITest2: ITestX
{
    void Read(string name);
}
```

and **ITestX**

```
public interface ITestX
{

}
```

The interfaces ITest1 and ITest1 are implemented in classes A and B:

```
public class A: ITest1 
{
    public void Write(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}

public class B: ITest2
{
    public void Read(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

As for the **factory**, my interface looks like this:

```
public interface IFactory
{
    ITestX GetClass(ClassType cType);
    ITestX GetClass(int cType);
}
```

The class **ClassType**:

```
public class ClassT
{
    public int Type { get; set; }

    public static class ClassType
    {
        public const int AType = 0;
        public const int BType = 1;
    }
}
```

The Factory class which implements the factory interface:

```
public class Factory : IFactory
    {
        public ITestX GetClass(ClassType cType)
        {
            return GetNetwork(networkType.Type);
        }

        public ITestX GetClass(int cType)
        {
            switch (cType)
            {
                case ClassT.ClassType.AType:
                    return new A();
                case ClassT.ClassType.BType:
                    return new B();
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
}
```

In my test method, I try to use the factory:

```
Factory factory = new Factory();
var typeClass = factory.GetClass(new ClassT{ Type = ClassT.ClassType.AType });
```

However, I can't use the `Read` or `Write` methods because they are not visible in `typeClass`. What's going on? Why can't I access them?

Comment: A factory pattern is supposed to create instances that share a common set of functionality.  Since your two interfaces are different, what were you expecting as a successful result?

Comment: @SteveMitcham What is my approach to use?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Your problem doesn't lend itself to a factory pattern, but since you have only told us about your implementation we can't help suggest another approach.  Add information about what your end goal is, why do you think a factory pattern is the approach you want?

Comment: @SteveMitcham I just want the output to have access to the methods of the selected class. But use my code, but use other pattern :)

Comment: The comment under my answer might give you the idea where this pattern is usefull

Comment: @user3406721 added another solution you could look at, i think it was your intention

Comment: @user3406721 i had overlooked that your classes are seperated at first sorry... and you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you rather need is this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadWriter myReadWriter = new ReadWriter(new ConsoleReaderWriterFactory());
        string test = myReadWriter.Read();
        myReadWriter.Write("this is abstract factory power");
    }
}

public class ConsoleWriter : ICanWrite
{
    public void Write(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}

public class ConsoleReader : ICanRead
{
    public string Read()
    {
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public interface ICanWrite
{
    void Write(string name);
}

public interface ICanReadAndWrite : ICanRead, ICanWrite { }

public interface ICanRead
{
    string Read();
}

public class ReadWriter : ICanReadAndWrite
{
    private ICanRead reader;
    private ICanWrite writer;

    public string Read()
    {
        return reader.Read();
    }

    public void Write(string name)
    {
        writer.Write(name);
    }

    public ReadWriter(IReaderWriterFactory factory)
    {
        reader = factory.CreateReader();
        writer = factory.CreateWriter();
    }
}

public interface IReaderWriterFactory
{
    ICanRead CreateReader();
    ICanWrite CreateWriter();
}

public class ConsoleReaderWriterFactory : IReaderWriterFactory
{
    public ICanRead CreateReader()
    {
        return new ConsoleReader();
    }

    public ICanWrite CreateWriter()
    {
        return new ConsoleWriter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `Factory.GetClass` returns `ITextX`, and this interface doesn't have that methods declared.

You can try casting that objects to the interface you need and then you will have an opportunity to invoke corresponding methods.

**UPDATE:**
You can see an example implementation on the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C.23).

Comment: The factory pattern is supposed to create classes of a common supertype, you have a common super- super type but that super super type is an empty interface

Comment: @user3406721 you can take a look at example in the link I have added to the answer.

Comment: @GoogleHireMe ok, but i have 2 interfaces with 2 other method. And if i inherit one interface in 2 classes i must implement two methods, but I do not want.

Comment: @user3406721 right. So, looks like Factory pattern isn't the best solution for you this time. Or you should consider changing some structure/logic of your program.

Comment: @GoogleHireMe What is my approach to use?

Comment: @user3406721 this is completely another question :) It depends on what you want to create. Can you give me more details? (or better ask another question here, at stackoverflow).

Comment: @GoogleHireMe I just want the output to have access to the methods of the selected class. But use my code, but use other pattern :)

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
public interface ICanRead
{
    string Read();
}

public interface ICanWrite
{
    void Write(string name);
}

public interface ICanReadAndWrite : ICanRead, ICanWrite {}


class ConsoleReadWriter : ICanReadAndWrite
{

    public string Read()
    {
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void Write(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}

public interface IReadWriterFactory
{
    ICanReadAndWrite GetClass();
}

public class ConsoleReadWriterFactory : IReadWriterFactory
{
    public ICanReadAndWrite GetClass()
    {
        return new ConsoleReadWriter();
    }
}
```

Create a class implementing the IReadWriterFactory interface for other Classes of ReadWriters.

Comment: So basically, reverse the inheritance relationship between the interfaces?

Comment: @JeffBridgman yes, exactly the mistake the op made... i think

Comment: the reason for implementing this pattern is that the factories could create a whole lot of objects that are not directly related to each other but only make sense when used together in a certain configuration and that the factories are interchangeable so you get a polymorphic creation of objectgroups

Comment: Then you'd be looking at Abstract Factory where you'd have a complete set of instantiations for the different related classes in different methods on the factory.  It's difficult to tell if that is the OPs intention here.